# Microservice dependency diagram

Tags: diagrams, sequence-diagram

What is the best way to capture dependency between microservices.
I want to create a diagram which show the interfaces and the microservices using the interfaces.

The aim is to easily do a impact analysis when any of the interfaces change.

Any tool or examples of such a diagram would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I draw these all the times - the "component diagram" in UML is what I use to represent the microservices and the interfaces that are shared and consumed between them.

Each "component" is often either one or more microservices working towards a common purpose.

These are particularly useful because they can show the interfaces that sub-components use too, so you can see the interfaces both within a component and which the components expose to other parts of the system.